# BeautifulSoup cannot display all data when scraping website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to scrape data from the cia website:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
from urllib.request import urlopen
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import requests

countries = ['af', 'ax']

def get_data(a):
    url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+a+'.html'
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    # geography
    try:
        country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
        map_reference = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-map-references'}).get_text(strip=True)
        return country, map_reference
    except(AttributeError) as e:
        print(e)

results = pd.DataFrame([get_data(p) for p in countries])
results
```

Which produces:

```
              0           1
0   Afghanistan Asia
1   Akrotiri    Middle East
```

But now when I try to add in another value `mean_elevation` into the same code:

```
countries = ['af', 'ax']

def get_data(a):
    url = 'https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/'+a+'.html'
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    # geography
    try:
        country = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'region'}).text
        map_reference = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-map-references'}).get_text(strip=True)
        mean_elevation = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'field-elevation'}).find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
        return country, map_reference, mean_elevation
    except(AttributeError) as e:
        print(e)

results = pd.DataFrame([get_data(p) for p in countries])
results
```

I get:

```
              0    1          2
0   Afghanistan Asia    1,884 m
1   None        None    None
```

I know it is because the second country 'ax' doesn't have that field but why does the entire row become None? What can I do to work around it and show data that are available and the non-available data blank?

Desired results:

```
              0           1        2
0   Afghanistan Asia         1,884 m
1   Akrotiri    Middle East  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this changes,

```
# fix : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

elevation = soup.find('div', {'id': 'field-elevation'})
if elevation:
    mean_elevation = elevation.find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
else:
    mean_elevation = ""
```

---

```
             0            1        2
0  Afghanistan         Asia  1,884 m
1     Akrotiri  Middle East
```

Comment: Seems to work thanks, if I have many columns like mean elevation would I have to do an if-statement for each?